# C++ conversion operator overload

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

'int' and 'double' conversion functions is 'explicit' and in this code why have I permit for use this conversion instead of error message?
If I delete all my conversion overload functions code occur 'conversion error'

```
class Person
{
public:
    Person(string s = "", int age = 0) :Name(s), Age(age) {}
    operator string() const { return Name; }
    explicit operator int() const{ return 10; }  // ! Explicit
    explicit operator double()const { return 20; } //! Explicit
    operator bool()const { if (Name != "") return true; return false; } // using this
};

int main(){

    Person a;
    int z = a;
    std::cout << z << std::endl;   // Why print "1"?  Why uses bool conversion?
}
```

I this it is answer:

Because 'a' can not be convert to int or double it occur error, but because it has bool conversion function, which can convert to int and int to double, code use this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int z = a;
```

Looks innocuous, right?

Well, the above line calls the implicit bool-conversion-operator, because that's the only way you left it to get from `Person` to `int`, and that only needs one user-defined conversion (the maximum allowed).

This is the reason for the safe-bool-idiom before C++11, and the major reason for the general advice to mark conversion operators and single-argument ctors `explicit` unless they are not transformative nor lossy.

If you want to see it for yourself, [fix your code and trace invocation of your `operator bool`](//coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99f4a5a9173a52a8).

Comment: Please don't confuse MS-mania typedefs and macros with standard types. And it's using `bool`-conversion because that's the only allowed path you left it. Just remember: All conversions, irrespective of using ctor or `operator`, should be `explicit` unless they do not loose information.

Comment: "Person to int, and it only needs one user-defined conversion." Yes. I think so. Thanks :)

Comment: Not good form.  Post the code solution here on SO, not some off-site link.

Comment: @Clifford The code was at most a side-note, and not running it looses all the impact. Anyway, reformulated to focus on the important part.

Comment: See the second bullet point in the "_Help others reproduce the problem_" section at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  I should have said " ... in addition to the off site link".